# How to append a UILabel to the end of text in another UILabel?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilabel, append, end-of-line

In my project, there's a UILabel in each UITableViewCell.
Text in each label varies from 1 line to 2 or 3 lines. (I get each text dynamically.)
I wonder how I can append another UILabel to the end of each text in UILabel.

I found this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607113/uiimage-in-the-end-of-uilabel-text) but the author didn't mention solution specifically.
Please let me share your ways and problem-solving. Thank you guys in advance!^^

I think I should add some information more.
For example, these are 2 labels.

---

This is the test Label for put in UITableView,

UITableViewCell 01/20

---

---

This is another label 01/19

---

Those dates(01/20, 01/19) that you can see next to each text are the another labels I wanna append. I can't append dates as a string directly cause the normal text and date are have different color and style. I tried 'sizeToFit' as some people told me, but that only show me a frame around whole text. What should I do T_T

Comment: Or is it possible to append some string(text) to the end of text in UILabel? That new string(text) has different font and color from those UILabel's text.

Comment: As mentionend in the link, can you try with an UIWebView instead of an UILabel?

Comment: Thank you for ur comment and then, should I make an web page like .html and call it in UIWebView? Is it ur meaning?

Comment: No, just make your label-string look like `NSString *html = @"<div>some text<br />some more text <img src='my.png' /></div>"` and call it with `[webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:nil];`.

Comment: Thank you 'ott--' very much!! I could make it thanks to ur help! I'm sad that I can't check your answer as my accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

As a variant:

```
UILabel *someLabel = ...
[someLabel setText:...]
[someLabel sizeToFit]
```

And then calculate the coordinates of the new insert UILabel.

Comment: OK, Thank u for you answer and I understand what u explain. Actually I am a kind of starter, so I hope u can let me know more detail..

Comment: sizeToFit only let me know the whole frame for text... It doesn't detect the exact location(position) of the text ended.

Answer (score 0):

```
[firstLabel sizeToFit];
CGRect frameForSecondLabel = CGRectMake(firstLabel.frame.origin.x+firstLabel.frame.size.width, firstLabel.frame.origin.y,width,height);
UILabel *secondLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:frameForSecondLabel];
```

I hope this is what you are looking for

Comment: Thank u for ur answer, but I think it's not exact answer for me. I updated my question, so please read my question again...